# SQL Server : selecting 'WEEKDAY' part by passing date in 'ddd' format

Tags: sql-server

How I can retrieve 'WEEKDAY' part by passing 'ddd' format in SQL Server?

For example in if I pass 'tue' and the response will be 3, beacuse

1 - Sunday
2 - Monday
3 - Tuesday

... like that.

I get the 'WEEKDAY' of current date by executing following query.

```
select DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: the value of `DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())` is actually depends on `DATEFIRST` settings.

Comment: I want to select 'WEEKDAY' part meas day in number format by passing 'ddd'.For example if i pass 'SUN' then i want to return 1.

Comment: if you are going to use the value 1 to determine the day of week, see my comments earlier. Your query might break if the datefirst settings is changed or the query is running in a DB with different language

Comment: Ok thanks  for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the day number for the given short day name honouring the current `DATEFIRST` setting.

```
--Example day name
DECLARE @Day CHAR(3) = 'Tue'

SELECT 
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DAY, Number, GETDATE())) DayNumber
FROM 
    master..spt_values N
WHERE 
    N.type = 'P' AND N.number BETWEEN 1 AND 7
    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DAY, Number, GETDATE())) LIKE @Day+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try similar to this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT 1 PK ,'Sunday' Value UNION 
    SELECT 2,'Monday' UNION
    SELECT 3,'Tuesday' UNION
    ...
    SELECT 7,'Saturday' 
)   T WHERE T.[Value] LIKE '%tue%'
```

Comment: Is any build in functions for that in sql

Comment: that will not be true for different `datefirst` settings

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT datepart(weekday,getdate()), datename(dw, getdate())
```

This will return the weekday and name of that day considering ISO_WEEK rule

[More detail here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the weekday no that is not dependant on `@@datefirst` or `langauge` setting

```
select  [weekday] = case @weekday_name
            when 'Sun' then (7 - @@datefirst + 0) % 7 + 1
            when 'Mon' then (7 - @@datefirst + 1) % 7 + 1
            when 'Tue' then (7 - @@datefirst + 2) % 7 + 1
            when 'Wed' then (7 - @@datefirst + 3) % 7 + 1
            when 'Thu' then (7 - @@datefirst + 4) % 7 + 1
            when 'Fri' then (7 - @@datefirst + 5) % 7 + 1
            when 'Sat' then (7 - @@datefirst + 6) % 7 + 1
            end
```